# Difference between Firebase AngularFire implicit and explicit sync

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am new to firebase. I want to build it with angularjs and I found angularfire.

In the angularFire docs listed
Implicit and explicit sync. I tried to understand the document in github but I still don't understand what is the difference and how to use them.
`angularFire()` and `angularFireCollection()`

also, what are the arguments mean in `angularFire()` and `angularFireCollection()`?

thank in adv

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use `angularFire` if you want implicit sync, i.e. any changes made to your model will instantly propagate to all other clients (and vice versa).

Use `angularFireCollection` if you want to be in control of when any local data changes must be sent to the server. Any remote changes will still automatically update your local collection.

Implicit sync:

```js
myapp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'angularFire',
  function MyCtrl($scope, angularFire) {
    var promise = angularFire(url, $scope, 'items', []);
  }
]);
```

First argument is the location of the Firebase at which you want to store/retrieve data. Second argument is the scope, third argument is the name of the property under $scope you want the data bound as soon as the promise is fulfilled. For example:

```js
promise.then(function() {
  // Data available in $scope.items
});
```

Fourth argument is the type of data you want in your JS object. Use `[]` for arrays, `{}` for objects, `""` for strings, `1` for numbers and `true` for boolean. Note that if no data is present in the provided Firebase location you can also use this argument to set the default value.

In implicit sync if you want to make any changes, simply modify `$scope.items` and the change will automatically synchronize with all other clients via Firebase. Similarly, any changes made remotely will automatically update `$scope.items`.

Explicit sync:

```js
myapp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'angularFireCollection',
  function MyCtrl($scope, angularFireCollection) {
    $scope.items = angularFireCollection(url);
  }
]);
```

This method only takes one argument. If you want to add or remove items, use the `add`, `remove` or `update` methods. For example:

```js
$scope.items.add({test: "object"});
```

Since `angularFireCollection` does not require a scope, you can also use this if you want to use Firebase outside of a controller (like angular directives, modules, etc.) Hope this helps!

Comment: I think you mean "implicit" instead of "explicit" in your first sentence.

Comment: In explicit sync. so we no longer use .on()  .set() .push() ?

Comment: Thanks @bennlich, fixed! @vzhen Nope, in explicit sync you only use `add()`, `remove()`, and `update()`.

Comment: Yes, i meant,  in explicit  we use add() remove()　and update().  we don't use set() push() right?   @Anant

Comment: @Anant I'm struggling with the explicit sync, in particular this piece `$scope.items = angularFireCollection(url);` ... this returns a collection however, my model `$scope.items` is an array ... how do I deal with this object?

Comment: @hagope, if you're dealing with arrays, I'd recommend using `angularFire` instead of `angularFireCollection`.

Comment: If we want to use implicit sync but also want to sync a collection we should use an array of the regular angularfire without using the collection?

Comment: @Harry, you can implicitly sync a regular object (collection) as well. angularFire(url, $scope, 'variable', []) will sync an array, angularFire(url, $scope, 'variable', {}) will sync an object.