# AngularJS: Using promises with firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm currently working on learning how to use AngularJS and Firebase.

I have a structure where I've set up services to handle interaction with Firebase, which is then used in the different controllers. I'm having problems with the data not being loaded when my code starts trying to use it. I've looked around and it seems to me promises is the solution.

I have a controller that looks like this:

```
app.controller('ExercisesCtrl', function ($scope, $location, $routeParams, Exercise) {

$scope.setExercise = function () {
    // set current exercise
    $scope.exercise = Exercise.find($routeParams.exerciseId).then( function () {
        // do something with the loaded data
    });
```

And a service which looks like this:

```
app.factory('Exercise',function ($firebase, FIREBASE_URL) {
var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + "exercises");
var exercises = $firebase(ref);

var exercise = {
    all: exercises,
    find: function (exerciseId) {
        return exercises.$child(exerciseId)
    }

};

return exercise;
```

});

My question is how I can change my current solution so that I can use .then or something similar to ensure that I don't start working with the data before it's loaded. I'm not sure if I should change the service to return a promise? Or just adopt the controller to wait for the data to be loaded?

This seemed relevant/linked, but was not sure if I should change my code to that structure or how to proceed from here. 
[Difference between Firebase AngularFire implicit and explicit sync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16733962/difference-between-firebase-angularfire-implicit-and-explicit-sync)

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at it freshly this morning, I realised that I had completely missed the events part in the angularfire documentation, which solves my problem nicely. It's available [here].[1](http://firebase.github.io/angularFire/documentation.html)

I ended up doing something like this:

```
$scope.exercise = Exercise.find($routeParams.exerciseId);
    var tasksRef = $scope.exercise.$child('tasks');
    tasksRef.$on("value", function(snap) {
        console.log(snap.snapshot.value);

        });
```

Using the $on method completely solves the issue.